# Defining a group of ports for SELinux

Tags: selinux

At my organization, we use a piece of software for instrumenting and monitoring our servers. Since this piece of software neither supports SELinux nor SystemD, we are currently working on improving its compatibility with CentOS/RHEL 7 by developing a SELinux policy module for it and exploring our options with SystemD.

SELinux comes first, and we need to allow this application to bind to a specific port or group of ports. Rather than simply hardcode a port that it's allowed to bind to, we'd like to follow the pattern of the reference implementation and define a `mymonitoringservice_port_t` and allow our running process to bind to any port with that type defined for it.

The difficulty that I'm having is that I can't seem to find how to define a port mapping type and a set of default values for it. Out of the box, the targeted policy defines the following for the `httpd_port_t`:

```
$ sudo semanage port -l | grep http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

I did not define these default port values, but somehow the policy did. I know that I can manage these port definitions by appending to and removing from this list, but as a policy maintainer, how can I "ship" the defaults to my servers? Is there a de-facto way of defining these port lists?

Comment: I may have found the definition [here](https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy/blob/f23-base/policy/modules/kernel/corenetwork.te.in#L182)